# Would it be possible to make a web/application server locally?

Tags: html, ffmpeg, html5-video

A little bit of background: I am trying to create a Google Chrome that will play videos in your browser locally. Meaning it should be able to play without an Internet connection. Since I'm only using HTML/Javascript, I can only play webm, mp4, and ogg files. However, I am interested in playing other formats, such as AVI, MPG, and maybe a few others. I was thinking of creating a local server somehow where I can run ffmpeg to encode the videos to webm/mp4. So my main objective is to get ffmpeg to run. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not just using html5 and javascript. If you have the option of running a local webserver than you can run any executable you want, including ffmpeg. You'll basically be calling a server side process (using php, java, or whatever) which happens to be running locally.

Comment: My intention is to run my application on different browsers (on different machines). Will I still be able to create a local web server?

Comment: Sure, it's simply a matter of choosing how you want to package and run it. It's really your preference but I'd go with an embedded jetty server packaged with your binaries in an executable jar file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download FFMPEG.EXE from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mplayer-win32/files/FFmpeg/old/)
2. Extract the FFMPEG.EXE from the archive.
3. Place the FFMPEG.EXE in the webdirectory.
4. As you all know how to upload a file (So i'm moving to the next step).
5. After the file uploaded just put the below line
   exec("ffmpeg -i recipe_videos/$path -f flv recipe_videos/$test[0].flv");
   //Format exec("ffmpeg -i pathofthevideouploaded -f towhichformat wherethefiletobesavedwithextension");
6. If you want delete the old file.
7. Now you can view the video in the desired format.

Comment: Thanks, but what I want is to be able run ffmpeg locally on any platform that I want.

Comment: I am trying to create a Google Chrome app that will play videos (all formats) locally. But since the HTML video tags has limited formats which it can play, I want to convert the videos to an appropriate format. Hence, the reason for my wanting to run "ffmpeg".

Comment: you can try what I have posted .. and you can post your question also at :http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-apps/topics?pli=1    sorry that for not giving you the right answer..

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is impossible. The browser prevents the server from accessing the user's computer (including running programs). You'll either need to transcode the videos on the server before serving them or have the user download FFmpeg and transcode the videos themselves.